# Links in SVG with Jquery mobile not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, svg

I am working with jQuery and jQuery Mobile to create a map with several elements on it. These elements should represent buildings or parts of buildings. If you click on them you should come to another page or a dialog box opens.

The best solution is to put the SVG code into the page because it is scaleable. The problem is now that the links around the paths do not work. They are shown in every browser and even the target-link is shown, but it just happens nothing. If I comment the embed of jquery mobile 1.4.5 out and it works just with jquery!

A code example with a example path in SVG. It shows a red square with the link to wikipedia. In jQuery it runs but not with jQuery Mobile:

```html
   <div data-role="content">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 525 365" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="map" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 <a xlink:href="//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">
 <path
  style="fill:#ff2700;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-
  linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;fill-opacity:1"
  d="M 24.243661,19.27897 230.31478,11.197749 222.23356,223.32978 18.182746,235.45161 z"
  id="path3773"
  inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
  transform="translate(216.65625,143.28125)" />
</a>
</svg>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this as well. A jQuery Mobile widget is hijacking the links, as already mentioned. This is the solution that's working for me so far: I add a `data-navigate` attribute on any link (could be any element) that is being hijacked and then add a global listener for the `vclick` (https://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/) event on elements with that attribute.

**HTML**

```
<svg...>
  <a xlink:href="/somepage.html" data-navigate="/somepage.html">
    <rect... />
  </a>
</svg>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('vclick', '[data-navigate'], function() {
  var url = $(this).data('navigate');

  // https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change
  $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', url);
});
```

Update: Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1658mafr/

Update #2: While this method works fine, when `somepage.html` in this example is loaded so are all the assets (JS, CSS); and if you hit the Back button from `somepage.html` the assets are again loaded. My understanding was that the `pagecontainer('change')` method should act the same as a clicked link, but apparently not. I'm researching this and will update as appropriate. For now be aware that this solution is defeating part of the reason for using JQM, which is only loading some of the larger assets once.